# What decides the number of water of crystallization molecules in a compound?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, coordination-compounds

[image][image: FeSO4.7H2O]CuSO<sub>4</sub>.5H<sub>2</sub>O, FeSO<sub>4</sub>.7H<sub>2</sub>O, ZnSO<sub>4</sub>.7H<sub>2</sub>O are some well known compounds. Known as blue, green and white vitriol respectively. As we can see the first compound has 5 molecules of water while the latter two have 7 each. What seems to decide the number?

It is stranger if we look into CaCl<sub>2</sub>.6H<sub>2</sub>O and MgCl<sub>2</sub>.7H<sub>2</sub>O. These compounds are chlorides  of Ca and Mg, present in the same group. However they don't have the same number of water of crystallization molecules. But why? **What dictates the number of water of crystallization molecules in a compound?**

Ps: 1. I know that the hydrated form of FeSO<sub>4</sub> is FeSO<sub>4</sub>.nH<sub>2</sub>O where n= 1,2,3,.. However, n=7 seems to be the most common. This is true for other examples in this question.

2. I thought about it for quite a while. I couldn't find a clear answer. However I have a guess.

FeSO<sub>4</sub>.7H<sub>2</sub>O has it's central atom Fe<sup>2+</sup> actually is bonded with 6 water molecules via coordinate bonding.

Fe<sup>2+</sup> = ... 3p<sub>x</sub><sup>2</sup> 3p<sub>y</sub><sup>2</sup> 3p<sub>z</sub><sup>2</sup> 3d<sub>xy</sub><sup>2</sup> 3d<sub>yz</sub><sup>1</sup> 3d<sub>xz</sub><sup>1</sup> 3d<sub>x<sup>2</sup>-z<sup>2</sup></sub><sup>1</sup> 3d<sub>z<sup>2</sup></sub><sup>1</sup> 4s<sup>0</sup>

Fe<sup>2+ *</sup> = ... 3p<sub>x</sub><sup>1</sup> 3p<sub>y</sub><sup>1</sup> 3p<sub>z</sub><sup>1</sup> 3d<sub>xy</sub><sup>1</sup> 3d<sub>yz</sub><sup>1</sup> 3d<sub>xz</sub><sup>1</sup> 3d<sub>x<sup>2</sup>-z<sup>2</sup></sub><sup>1</sup> 3d<sub>z<sup>2</sup></sub><sup>1</sup> 4s<sup>1</sup> 4p<sub>x</sub><sup>1</sup> 4p<sub>y</sub><sup>1</sup> 4p<sub>z</sub><sup>1</sup>

and then 6 water molecules create coordination bonding with Fe<sup>2+*</sup> by donating electrons to these twelve orbitals and filling thsese orbitals. However, **this is simply an educated guess and can't explain the examples.**

**I would much appreciate any help. I am open for a discussion**. Thanks for reading!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What determines how much water of crystallisation a salt has?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/78929/what-determines-how-much-water-of-crystallisation-a-salt-has)

Comment: @NilayGhosh sadly, it doesn't.

Comment: I kinda agree. That answer should have more details but the core question is already asked in that post. Maybe if we get a good answer here, we will close the other one.

Comment: Also see: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/60378/why-does-oxalic-acid-have-exactly-two-water-molecules-of-crystallization

Comment: Am I missing something or is your post missing something? You seem to have posted the same image twice.

Comment: @BuckThorn It was a technical problem, sorry for the confusion. Thanks for notifying. I was and still am on my phone, so I am facing a little problem writing. Cheers!